# Error in reading file input: Not terminating and returning results for some .txt inputs

Tags: c++, cin, avl-tree

I am trying to program an AVL tree in c++. My professor has provided a main.cpp, as well as a file for insertion and several for deletion, to allow for testing. My program correctly takes the insertion file, and the first of the deletion files, but fails to return a result for the rest of the deletion files. I am unsure if this is due to an error with the file reading, or those files create cases where I have a loop not exiting, etc.

I have tried inserting cout statements to track where the code goes, but haven't gotten any useful results for debugging. The program never displays the results for the 2nd, 3rd, or 4th deletion files, only the first. I have also tried starting with each deletion file on a fresh make.

My main.cpp (as provided by the instructor) is as follows:

```cpp
#include "utility.h"
#include "Binary_node.h"
#include "Binary_tree.h"
#include "Search_tree.h"
#include "AVL_node.h"
#include "AVL_tree.h"


int main(){
   string input = "";
   bool exit_now = false;
   AVL_tree<int> atree;
   while(!exit_now){
      cout << endl;
      cout << "***********************" << endl;
      cout << "Menu:" << endl;
      cout << "1. Incremental Insert" << endl;
      cout << "2. Insert from File" << endl;
      cout << "3. Incremental Delete" << endl;
      cout << "4. Delete from File" << endl;
      cout << "p. Print tree" << endl;
      cout << "x. Exit" << endl;
      cout << "***********************" << endl;

      getline(cin, input);

      if(input == "1"){
         cout << endl;
         cout << "Enter new integer keys to insert.  Enter \"q<Enter>\" to quit." << endl;
         cout << endl;
         getline(cin, input);
         while(input != "q"){
            atree.insert(string_to_int(input));
            atree.print();            
            getline(cin, input);
         }
      } 
      else if(input == "2"){
         cout << endl << "Enter Insertion File Name:" << endl;
         getline(cin, input);
         ifstream insertion_file;
         insertion_file.open(input.c_str());
         if(!insertion_file.fail()){
            while(!insertion_file.fail() && !insertion_file.eof()){
               getline(insertion_file, input);
               atree.insert(string_to_int(input));
            }
            atree.print();
         } else
            cout << "Invalid file name." << endl;
      }
      else if(input == "3"){
         cout << endl;
         cout << "Enter integer keys to delete.  Enter \"q<Enter>\" to quit." << endl;
         cout << endl;
         getline(cin, input);
         while(input != "q"){
            atree.remove(string_to_int(input));
            atree.print();            
            getline(cin, input);
         }
      } 
      else if(input == "4"){
         cout << endl << "Enter Deletion File Name:" << endl;
         getline(cin, input);
         ifstream deletion_file;
         deletion_file.open(input.c_str());
         if(!deletion_file.fail()){
            while(!deletion_file.fail() && !deletion_file.eof()){
               getline(deletion_file, input);
               atree.remove(string_to_int(input));
            }
            atree.print();
         } else
            cout << "Invalid file name." << endl;
      }
      else if (input == "p")
         atree.print();
      else if(input == "x")
         exit_now = true;
   }

}
```

My avl_delete function and it's auxiliary functions are as follows:

```cpp
template <class Record>
Error_code AVL_tree<Record>::avl_delete(Binary_node<Record>* &sub_root,
           const Record &old_data, bool &shorter)
{
   //If key not found
   if (sub_root == NULL) return not_present;
   //Key is less than current subroot's value
   else if (old_data < sub_root->data){
      avl_delete(sub_root->left, old_data, shorter);
   }
   //Key is greater than current subroot's value
   else if (old_data > sub_root->data){
      avl_delete(sub_root->right, old_data, shorter);
   }
   //Key found, delete this
   else
   {
      //Create a temp node
      Binary_node<Record> *temp;

      //No child case
      if (sub_root->left == NULL && sub_root->right == NULL){
         temp = sub_root;
         sub_root = NULL;
         delete temp;
         shorter = true;
      }
      //No left child case
      else if (sub_root->left == NULL){
         temp = sub_root->right;
         sub_root = temp;
         delete temp;
         shorter = true;
      }
      //No right child case
      else if (sub_root->right == NULL){
         temp = sub_root->left;
         sub_root = temp;
         delete temp;
         shorter = true;
      }
      //Two child case
      else {
         //Find immediate successor
         temp = sub_root->right;
         while (sub_root->left != NULL){
            temp = sub_root->left;
         }

         //Change the value of the deleted Node's key to that of it's immediate successor
         sub_root->data = temp->data;

         //Delete the immediate successor
         avl_delete(sub_root->right, temp->data, shorter);
      }
   }

   //If tree's only node has been deleted
   if (sub_root == NULL) return success;

   //Handle rebalancing cases (only if shorter == true)
   if (shorter) {
      //Reset shorter to false. Will be changed back to true to propogate in cases where appropriate
      shorter = false;

      if (sub_root->get_balance() == equal_height) {
         if (old_data < sub_root->data) sub_root->set_balance(right_higher);
         else if (old_data > sub_root->data) sub_root->set_balance(left_higher);
      }
      else if (sub_root->get_balance() == right_higher) {
         //This case is unbalanced
         if (old_data < sub_root->data){
            right_balance(sub_root);
            //Check to see whether to propogate shorter
            if (sub_root->get_balance() == equal_height) shorter = true;
         }
         else if (old_data > sub_root->data) {
            sub_root->set_balance(equal_height);
            shorter = true;
         }
      }
      else if (sub_root->get_balance() == left_higher) {
         if (old_data < sub_root->data){
            sub_root->set_balance(equal_height);
            shorter = true;
         }
         //This case is unbalanced
         else if (old_data > sub_root->data) {
            left_balance(sub_root);
            //Check to see whether to propogate shorter
            if (sub_root->get_balance() == equal_height) shorter = true;
         }
      }
   }

   return success;
}




template <class Record>
void AVL_tree<Record>::left_balance(Binary_node<Record>* &sub_root)
/*
Pre:  sub_root points to a subtree of an AVL_tree that
      is doubly unbalanced on the left.
Post: The AVL properties have been restored to the subtree.
Uses: 

*/
{
   Binary_node<Record>* &left_tree = sub_root->left;
   // case left_higher: single right rotation
   //    O  ub --> subroot
   //   /
   //  O  lh  --> left_tree
   // /
   //O
   switch (left_tree->get_balance()) {
   case left_higher:  //  single right rotation
      sub_root->set_balance(equal_height);
      left_tree->set_balance(equal_height);
      rotate_right(sub_root); //pointer adjustment
      break;
   case equal_height:  //  impossible case
      cout << "WARNING: If you see this in an insertion, program error is detected in left_balance" << endl;
      left_tree->set_balance(right_higher);
      rotate_right(sub_root);
      break;
   // case left_higher: double rotation left
   //     O ub --> sub_root
   //    /
   //   O rh --> left_tree
   //   \
   //    O three cases --> sub_tree
   case right_higher:                           
      Binary_node<Record> *sub_tree = left_tree->right;
      //set balance of sub_root and left_tree assuming rotation is done
      switch (sub_tree->get_balance()) {
      case equal_height:
         sub_root->set_balance(equal_height);
         left_tree->set_balance(equal_height);
         break;
      case left_higher:
         sub_root->set_balance(right_higher);
         left_tree->set_balance(equal_height);
         break;
      case right_higher:
         sub_root->set_balance(equal_height);
         left_tree->set_balance(left_higher);
         break;
      }
      //set balance of sub_tree after rotation
      sub_tree->set_balance(equal_height);
      //perform actual rotation
      rotate_left(left_tree);
      rotate_right(sub_root);
      break;
   }

}


template <class Record>
void AVL_tree<Record>::right_balance(Binary_node<Record> *&sub_root)
/*
Pre:  sub_root points to a subtree of an AVL_tree that
      is unbalanced on the right.
Post: The AVL properties have been restored to the subtree.
Uses: Methods of struct AVL_node;
      functions  rotate_right and rotate_left.
*/
{
   Binary_node<Record>* &right_tree = sub_root->right;
   // case right_higher: sigle left rotation
   // O  ub --> subroot
   //  \
   //   O  rh  --> right_tree
   //    \
   //     O
   switch (right_tree->get_balance()) {
   case right_higher:  //  single left rotation
      sub_root->set_balance(equal_height);
      right_tree->set_balance(equal_height);
      rotate_left(sub_root); //pointer adjustment
      break;
   case equal_height:  //  impossible case
      cout << "WARNING: If you see this in an insertion, program error is detected in right_balance" << endl;
      right_tree->set_balance(left_higher);
      rotate_left(sub_root);
      break;
   // case left_higher: double rotation left
   // O ub --> sub_root
   //  \
   //   O lh --> right_tree
   //  /
   // O three cases --> sub_tree
   case left_higher:                           
      Binary_node<Record> *sub_tree = right_tree->left;
      //set balance of sub_root and right_tree assuming rotation is done
      switch (sub_tree->get_balance()) {
      case equal_height:
         sub_root->set_balance(equal_height);
         right_tree->set_balance(equal_height);
         break;
      case left_higher:
         sub_root->set_balance(equal_height);
         right_tree->set_balance(right_higher);
         break;
      case right_higher:
         sub_root->set_balance(left_higher);
         right_tree->set_balance(equal_height);
         break;
      }
      //set balance of sub_tree after rotation
      sub_tree->set_balance(equal_height);
      //perform actual rotation
      rotate_right(right_tree);
      rotate_left(sub_root);
      break;
   }
}


//adjustment of pointers
template <class Record>
void AVL_tree<Record>::rotate_left(Binary_node<Record> *&sub_root)
/*
Pre:  sub_root points to a subtree of the AVL_tree.
      This subtree has a nonempty right subtree.
Post: sub_root is reset to point to its former right child, and the former
      sub_root node is the left child of the new sub_root node.
*/
{
   if (sub_root == NULL || sub_root->right == NULL)     //  impossible cases
      cout << "WARNING: program error detected in rotate_left" << endl;
   else {
      Binary_node<Record> *right_tree = sub_root->right;
      sub_root->right = right_tree->left;
      right_tree->left = sub_root;
      sub_root = right_tree;
   }
}


template <class Record>
void AVL_tree<Record>::rotate_right(Binary_node<Record> *&sub_root)
/*
Pre:  sub_root points to a subtree of the AVL_tree.
      This subtree has a nonempty left subtree.
Post: 
*/
{
   if (sub_root == NULL || sub_root->left == NULL)     //  impossible cases
      cout << "WARNING: program error detected in rotate_right" << endl;
   else {
      Binary_node<Record> *left_tree = sub_root->left;
      sub_root->left = left_tree->right;
      left_tree->right = sub_root;
      sub_root = left_tree;
   }

}
```

Expected results would yield a printed list of key values, and the key values of the right and left children of its corresponding nodes. The overall structure is an AVL tree.

Comment: Seems like you should learn how to use a debugger and trace what your program does. I don't see any obvious errors at first glance.

Comment: Does your deletion file contain a single integer?

Comment: The deletion file is just a .txt file with some integers in it.